# Ensure SQL changes carry over

Tags: theme-development, mysql

I was working on some site that has the excerpt on a serialized meta field. Since we're not supporting that plugin anymore I just migrated it with SQL.

Encoding seems fine here:

[image]

However on wp-admin:

[image]

What am I missing to make sure the changes are carried over?

Comment: This is not issue. You must check that data is copied in that way.

Comment: What does that mean? You can see in SQL that it's fine

Comment: I am not getting you. Its still unclear

Comment: Excerpt on SQL looks correct. Excerpt on wp-admin does not.

Comment: If you have custom code let me know

Comment: Did you migrate it from one database to another? My first thought is that the character encoding is different between the source and destination.

Comment: No, I did not do that. It was created with PHP and you can see within SQL that is correct. It's just different on SQL vs Wordpress Admin